# issues upgrading Ember 1.8.1 to Ember 1.9.1 with Handlebars 2.0 and emblem

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, emblem.js

Im wondering if anyone came across this issue with upgrading Emberjs from 1.8.1 to 1.9.1

I am getting this error in my dev console

```
This link-to is in an inactive loading state because at least one of its parameters presently has a null/undefined value, or the provided route name is invalid.
```

Besides upgrading to Ember 1.9.1 and Handlebars 2.0
I am also using gulp-auto-emblem
I have checked https://github.com/machty/emblem.js/ and it seems like no support for Handlebars 2.0 yet..

I have found a solution to fix the link-to issue by doing this:

`link-to 'report.index' report`

but i need to have class names in my link-top helper

`link-to 'report.index' report id class='button button--viewReport'`

but this doesnt work..

any feedback would be appreciated.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `classNames` instead of `class`

```
link-to 'report.index' report id classNames='button button--viewReport'
```